# Save images from URL with increasing number

Tags: php, curl

I have the following URL,

http://site.com/productphotos/gallery_[1-1000]-l.jpg

After gallery_ there is a random number between 1 and 1000, how can I save all these images without saving them one by one with PHP?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what you mean by save - are creating it or coping or ... ?

Comment: They need to be saved one by one, you can use a loop though.

Comment: Any program you do it in will ultimately save them one by one...

Answer (score 0):

You have to save them one by one. What you could do is using a keep-alive HTTP connection to transfer them - that would save some time.

Answer (score 0):

curl "http://site.com/productphotos/gallery_[1-1000]-l.jpg" -O

But this will try *all* numbers between 1 and 1000 so you'll get those files created as well with 404 responses. You may avoid the 404s by additionally using the -f option.